# FastPdfKit - UI Missing after implementation of didReceiveDoubleTapOnAnnotationRect

Tags: ios, pdf, delegates

Using FastPdfKit ([FastPdfKit sdk site](http://fastpdfkit.com/)), I have implemented `documentViewController:didReceiveDoubleTapOnAnnotationRect` with the following code:

```
-(void)documentViewController:(MFDocumentViewController *)dvc didReceiveTapOnAnnotationRect:(CGRect)rect withUri:(NSString *)uri onPage:(NSUInteger)page {    
  NSArray *arrayParameter = nil;
  NSString *uriType = nil;
  NSString *uriResource = nil;

  arrayParameter = [uri componentsSeparatedByString:@"://"];

  uriType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayParameter objectAtIndex:0]];

  uriResource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayParameter objectAtIndex:1]];

  if ([uriType isEqualToString:@"pamv1"]) {
    NSString *marker = uriResource;
    NSLog(@"Marker: %@", marker);
  }
}
```

This works, to a point. When I double tap on an annotation, the output from NSLog shows:

```
2012-03-15 17:37:53:599 iFlightBag[8286:1799] -[ManualsListViewController documentViewController:didReceiveDoubleTapOnAnnotationRect:withUri:onPage:] [Line 155] Marker: Builtin_Manual_IOM_annotations.pdf?page=3&paragraph=6&edit=0
```

The problem: When I set the delegate, I lose the built-in reader UI: tap for the menu, done button, thumbnails, etc... I still have swipe and tap-on-edge to change pages, double-tap (on a non-annotated section) and pinch to zoom. So I am unable to exit the viewer (and all other function from the control UI). I set the delegate using:

```
[pdfViewController setDocumentDelegate:self];
```

The whole code to implement FastPdfKit in my app is (mostly from their example):

```
-(void)openFastPdfURL:(NSURL *)documentUrl {

  // TestFlight api
  TESTFLIGHT_CHECKPOINT(@"ManualsFastPdfKit");

  /** Set document name */
  NSString *documentName = [documentUrl lastPathComponent];

  /** Get temporary directory to save thumbnails */
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  /** Set thumbnails path */
  NSString *thumbnailsPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",documentName]];

  /** Get document from the App Bundle */
  // NSURL *documentUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"pdf"]];

  /** Instancing the documentManager */
  MFDocumentManager *documentManager = [[MFDocumentManager alloc]initWithFileUrl:documentUrl];

  /** Instancing the readerViewController */
  ReaderViewController *pdfViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc]initWithDocumentManager:documentManager];

  /** Set resources folder on the manager */
  documentManager.resourceFolder = thumbnailsPath;

  /** Set document id for thumbnail generation */
  pdfViewController.documentId = documentName;

  /** Set the delegate */
  [pdfViewController setDocumentDelegate:self];

  /** Present the pdf on screen in a modal view */
  [self presentModalViewController:pdfViewController animated:YES]; 

  /** Release the pdf controller*/
  [pdfViewController release];
}
```

and in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
// fastPdfKit
else if ([manuals.Format isEqualToString:@"fastpdf"]) {
    [self openFastPdfURL:[self locateUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:manuals.Url] ofType:[manuals.Url pathExtension]]];
}
```

My goals:
1. Have a fast, internal PDF reader (complete)
2. Process custom annotations (in progress)

I also need to keep the reader UI for the user to process bookmarks, search, thumbnails, end the viewer, etc...

If I comment out the

```
[pdfViewController setDocumentDelegate:self];
```

line, the full UI comes back. Has anyone implemented FastPdfKit's annotation interface?

Comment: did you solve the issue?? Can i have some samples??How its resolved?

Comment: @Lithu Thiruvathira, no. I've put the annotation project on hold until I can get this working.